# A Completely solo Pathfinder game

Tags: pathfinder-1e, solo

I'm in need of a system that allows me to play a completely solo Pathfinder game.  I've been searching for a while now, and most people either say: "You can't, play it with friends", or "you can", but they never give me any good advice on how.

My major problem is:

I want the story to be interesting.  If you are simultaneously the player and the DM, any surprise or interest is gone in any event.

With the above considered, I need to find a way to play the game without a pre-written story. Some have said that there are books that do this, but I don't have money of any kind, and I want to create my own story rather than one that I'm generally uninterested in and that has no replayability.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? It almost sounds like you want to write a story in Golarion while rolling dice, and if that is what you want you can certainly just do that without further advice.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. This sounds like you're asking for recommendations rather than methods, and while the site can help with the latter, it can't with the former, [recommendations being off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/8610). [However, a forum might be able to help](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610). If, instead, you rephrased the question to *Can I play* Pathfinder *solo without additional books?* that might be a worthwhile question. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Specifically, I want a way of creating the story as I play, so everything that happens is unpredictable.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman he wants a way to make a solo RPG game that looks like a surprise for himself. It doesn't even need to be tailored for PF. I made my shot at an answer below.

Comment: The AD&D 1e Dungeon Masters Guide had three appendices (A, B, and C) for random dungeons, random wilderness encounters, and random monsters.  Is what you have in mind random encounters that you roll up so that you don't know what is coming next, or are you looking for something more than that?  The PFSRD has a [random encounter generator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/random-encounter-generators).  What (beyond that) are you looking for to make this solo campaign work for you?